# QR Code Scanner SDK for Mac?

Tags: macos, sdk, qr-code

There seems to be plenty of QR Code SDKs for iPhone, but the ones I've found reference frameworks that are unavailable on Mac, such as UIKit. I would like to be able to scan QR codes using the webcam on a Mac from a Mac App. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a complete implementation, but there's cocoa support in the [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) library. It should get you started at least.

Answer (score 1):

zxing has this. See the objc directory. Not much in the way of docs, but it has examples. Feel free to post to the zxing google group if you have trouble.

[full disclosure: I'm the author/maintainer of the objc interface classes.]